# Slicing the substring from the string in each row of the column using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am absolute beginner. I have a problem in slicing string in a Excel file using Python. My Excel file contains the following info:

```
Column 1:

ordercode   
PMC11-AA1L1FAVWJA   
PMC21-AA1A1CBVXJA   
PMP11-AA1L1FAWJJ    
PMP21-AA1A1FBWJJ    
PMP23-AA1A1FA3EJ+JA
PTP31B-AA3D1HGBVXJ  
PTC31B-AA3D1CGBWBJA 
PTP33B-AA3D1HGB1JJ
```

I want to slice the string in column "ordercode" based on whether it is
"PMC11"/"PMC21"/"PMP21"/"PMP11"/"PMP23"/"PTP31B"/"PTP33B"/"PTC31B" at different position and save it in new column "pressurerange". In Excel I have used the below code and it worked fine:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PMC11",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PMC21",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PMP11",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PMP21",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PMP23",A2))),MID(A2,11,2),MID(A2,12,2))
```

but in Python I used the below coding, and it didn't work properly.

Python Code:

```
import pandas as pd
#Assigning the worksheet to file
file="Stratification_worksheet.xlsx"
#Loading the spreadsheet 
data= pd.ExcelFile(file)
#sheetname
print(data.sheet_names)
#loading the sheetname to df1
df=data.parse("Auftrag")
print(df)

#creating a new column preessurerange and slicing the pressure range from order code

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if "PMC11" in df.loc[index,"ordercode"]:
        df["pressurerange"]=df["ordercode"].str.slice(10,12)
    elif "PMC21" in df.loc[index,"ordercode"]:
        df["pressurerange"]=df["ordercode"].str.slice(10,12)
    elif "PMP11" in df.loc[index,"ordercode"]:
        df["pressurerange"]=df["ordercode"].str.slice(10,12)
    elif "PMP21" in df.loc[index,"ordercode"]:
        df["pressurerange"]=df["ordercode"].str.slice(10,12)
    elif "PMP23" in df.loc[index,"ordercode"]:
        df["pressurerange"]=df["ordercode"].str.slice(10,12)
    elif "PTP31B" in df.loc[index,"ordercode"]:
        df["pressurerange"]=df["ordercode"].str.slice(11,13)
    elif "PTP33B" in df.loc[index,"ordercode"]:
        df["pressurerange"]=df["ordercode"].str.slice(11,13)
    elif "PTC31B" in df.loc[index,"ordercode"]:
        df["pressurerange"]=df["ordercode"].str.slice(11,13)
    else:
        df["pressurerange"]="NONE"
    print(df.loc[:,["pressurerange"]])
    break
```

Here what it does is it checked the first IF condition and it sliced the string at the position (10,12) for all the column. I know I have done mistake in the below code. But I don't know what is the exact code to use.

```
=df["pressurerange"]=df["ordercode"].str.slice(10,12)
```

Comment: I need to extract the string "1F"/"1C"/"1H" from the string. which is positioned at (10,12) for "PMC11,PMC21,PMP21,PMP11,PMP23" and for "PTP31B,PTP33B,PTC31B" it is positioned at (11,13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genera solution working with data with no `-`, then are returned `NaN`s.

I believe need [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with conditions created by [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
L1 = ["PMC11","PMC21","PMP21","PMP11","PMP23"]
L2 = ["PTP31B","PTP33B","PTC31B"]
m1 = df["ordercode"].str.startswith(tuple(L1))
m2 = df["ordercode"].str.startswith(tuple(L2))

a = df["ordercode"].str.slice(10,12)
b = df["ordercode"].str.slice(11,13)

df["pressurerange"] = np.select([m1, m2], [a, b], default=np.nan)
print (df)
             ordercode pressurerange
0    PMC11-AA1L1FAVWJA            1F
1    PMC21-AA1A1CBVXJA            1C
2     PMP11-AA1L1FAWJJ            1F
3     PMP21-AA1A1FBWJJ            1F
4  PMP23-AA1A1FA3EJ+JA            1F
5   PTP31B-AA3D1HGBVXJ            1H
6  PTC31B-AA3D1CGBWBJA            1C
7   PTP33B-AA3D1HGB1JJ            1H
```

---

If all values have `-` solution should be simplify with [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), then select second lists by `str[1]` and last select `5-6` character by `str[4:6]` or [`Series.str.slice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html):

```
df["pressurerange"] = df['ordercode'].str.split('-', n=1).str[1].str[4:6]
#alternative solution
#df["pressurerange"] = df['ordercode'].str.split('-', n=1).str[1].str.slice(4,6)
print (df)
             ordercode pressurerange
0    PMC11-AA1L1FAVWJA            1F
1    PMC21-AA1A1CBVXJA            1C
2     PMP11-AA1L1FAWJJ            1F
3     PMP21-AA1A1FBWJJ            1F
4  PMP23-AA1A1FA3EJ+JA            1F
5   PTP31B-AA3D1HGBVXJ            1H
6  PTC31B-AA3D1CGBWBJA            1C
7   PTP33B-AA3D1HGB1JJ            1H
```

Comment: This seems a bit complicated for what is really a very simple problem?

Comment: @alkanen - Thank you for feed back, +3

Comment: For what it's worth, I think your solution is pretty nifty =)

Comment: @jezrael Thanks. its easy and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Python gives you a lot more options than Excel. If you have a string `code = "PMC21-AA1A1CBVXJA"`, you can write

```
pressurerange, rest = code.split("-")
```

and you have the part before the `-` and the part after. I'll let you figure out how to use this in your workflow.

(Note: If the `rest` part can contain additional hyphens, use `code.split("-", 1)` to limit the splitting to one match.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use split:

```
string = 'PMC11-AA1L1FAVWJA'
pressure_range, columns = string.split('-', 1)
column = columns[4:6]
```